# Unknown column 'admin_clients.org_password' in 'field list' but field exist

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to access the data from the database but its showing error (Unknown column 'admin_clients.org_password' in 'field list'). But from the database org_password field exits.

In Model:-

```
 function adminloginMe($email, $password)
    {
        $this->db->select('admin_clients.admin_clients_id,admin_clients.org_password,admin_clients.org_name,admin_clients.roleId,admin_clients.role');
        $this->db->from('admin_clients as admin_clients');
        $this->db->where('admin_clients.org_mail', $email);
        $this->db->where('admin_clients.isDeleted', 0);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $user = $query->row();
}
```

Check the image link for database result.
[image: Query result check the image link]

How to solve it.

Comment: please post a create table and see if there are typos

Comment: CREATE TABLE `admin_clients` (
  `admin_clients_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `org_name` text NOT NULL,
  `org_mail` text NOT NULL,
  `org_password` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `org_contact_no` double NOT NULL,
  `package` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `roleId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `role` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'System Administrator',
  `isDeleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `added_date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: Any solution `CREATE TABLE `admin_clients` (
  `admin_clients_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `org_name` text NOT NULL,
  `org_mail` text NOT NULL,
  `org_password` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `org_contact_no` double NOT NULL,
  `package` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `roleId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `role` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'System Administrator',
  `isDeleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `added_date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
`

Comment: this is usually a sign that you are connected to another server . another point save passwords only hashed